# In JPA : Attempt to continue working after transaction rolledback

Tags: jpa

I am getting error like below while fetching any record from table :

> Attempt to continue working after transaction rolledback
>   collection was processed twice by flush()

JPA entity :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = DataModelConstants.ENTITY_DEAL)
public class Deal {

    @Column(name = "OPTY_ID")
    private String optyId;
}
```

Comment: we are fetching with find query

Comment: Well show some more code, there seems to be nothing wrong with the entity